# Multilingual website URLs

Tags: sql, database, multilingual

I am just researching building a multilingual website. I've looked into database structure but I am now looking at how the URLs would work.

My main concern is that I will have an English and Chinese version of the website. I want to use search engine friendly URLs, how would this be possible with Chinese characters?

For the English site I may use something like:

```
www.domain.com/en/products/[productname]/
```

With the product name coming from the English translation in the database.

What would I do for the Chinese website?

```
www.domain.com/cn/products/[productname]/
```

Would I just be able to put the Chinese translation from the database straight into the URL?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Wikipedia? For instance https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BB%9F%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%84%E6%BA%90%E5%AE%9A%E4%BD%8D%E7%AC%A6

Comment: Yes I did see that whilst searching around, so I can just use Chinese symbols in the URL, but unsure if thats for all languages as the site may be developed to include more later so will have to research.

Answer (score 0):

from [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> When encoding a String, the following rules apply:
>
> The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0"
>   through "9" remain the same. The special characters ".", "-", "*", and
>   "_" remain the same. The space character " " is converted into a plus
>   sign "+". All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into
>   one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is
>   represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit
>   hexadecimal representation of the byte. The recommended encoding
>   scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an
>   encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform
>   is used.

So do the encoding as specified. I guess the search engines will decode them correctly.